Remix App Deployed on Vercel Only Loading Index
I've just deployed a remix app to vercel. The local dev version of the site works fine but when I go to the production version, I can't load any other page but the index. If I go to one of my other routes, the page will load for a second and then will return a 404 error. I've looked at the console and have seen a react #418 and #423 error denoting something to do with hydration, but I don't know what the issue could be because when I would put the html from the routes into index, they'd render fine. I've seen posts saying to use a vercel.json file in the root with the following code:
{
    "routes": [{ "src": "/[^.]+", "dest": "/", "status": 200 }]
}

But that hasn't worked either. I've tried using the Vercel CLI and also just deploying straight from Github but neither has worked either. Any help would be appreciated.

Verify that the src pattern (/[^.]+) matches your route structure correctly. This pattern captures all routes except those ending with a dot (.).

@RaviChauhan none of my routes end in a dot
